# Unexpected import behavior: sys.modules is checked twice?

Tags: python, import, python-import

Consider the following scenario:

script.py:

```
import sys
import cant_import_this

print(cant_import_this)
print(cant_import_this is sys)
```

cant_import_this.py:

```
import sys
sys.modules['cant_import_this'] = sys
```

The output of `script.py` is, surprisingly:

```
<module 'sys' (built-in)>
True
```

---

What seems to be happening is:

1. `import cant_import_this` checks if `cant_import_this` exists in `sys.modules`
2. `cant_import_this` can't be found in `sys.modules`, so `cant_import_this.py` is found and loaded
3. the uninitialized `cant_import_this` module is put into `sys.modules`
4. the module is executed, which removes `cant_import_this` from `sys.modules` and replaces it with `sys`
5. instead of returning the module itself, the result of the lookup `sys.modules['cant_import_this']` is returned

Is this interpretation correct? More importantly, is this behavior documented anywhere? Could it possibly be considered a bug?

Comment: I think you have steps 3 and 4 reversed. Python cannot add a module to `sys.modules` until it has actually finished creating it, but by the time `can't_import_this` has been created, there is already an entry for that name in `sys.modules`, so it is left alone.

Comment: @chepner I think we aren't on the same page about what "initialized" and "created" means. If I understand your comment correctly, you're saying that `cant_import_this` is executed _before_ it is added to `sys.modules`? If so, you're incorrect - I can add `print(sys.modules['cant_import_this'])` to `cant_import_this.py` and it will run without throwing a `KeyError`.

Comment: Hm, yes. I guess that means the `module` instance is created, but populated after the fact?

Comment: @chepner Yes, [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#loading) say: _"The module will exist in sys.modules before the loader executes the module code. This is crucial because the module code may (directly or indirectly) import itself; adding it to sys.modules beforehand prevents unbounded recursion in the worst case and multiple loading in the best."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in [a footnote](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#fnlo):

> The importlib implementation avoids using the return value directly.
>   Instead, it gets the module object by looking the module name up in
>   sys.modules. The indirect effect of this is that an imported module
>   may replace itself in sys.modules. This is implementation-specific
>   behavior that is not guaranteed to work in other Python
>   implementations.

So it's not a bug, but it can't be relied on either.